# Where is the result of each function call stored in this factorial method?

Tags: javascript, recursion, factorial

Here is an object with a method that will return the factorial of a number via recursion. What I can't wrap my head around is where the value of the `factorialized` variable is being stored when the function calls itself again and multiplies `inputNumber` by itself `-1`. Could someone explain this to me?

```js
const Calculate = {
  factorial(inputNumber) {
    if (inputNumber < 2) { return 1 };
    const factorialized = inputNumber * this.factorial(inputNumber - 1);
    
    return factorialized;
    }
  }

Calculate.factorial(5);
```

Comment: Take a look at how the call stack works https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: The function is recursive and it keeps calling itself: hence passing the value forward until a certain condition is met that breaks the recursion (refer to the if statement).

Comment: Put very simply, the JavaScript engine keeps the intermediate result in memory (the computer's RAM) until it is no longer needed. It works exactly like local variables; they are stored in memory until the function finishes, then the memory is freed again. You don't have to worry about any of that; the engine takes care of it. Also, you don't have to look at factorials for this, a simple expression like `Math.root(2) + Math.root(3)` does the same thing until the expression is fully evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many language has `Memory Heap` to save value for their operations, etc.

Image your function will execute 3 times:

- the the result from 1th execution will be allocate to [k] position of `Memory Heap`
- then the 2th execution will allocate to [k+1] position
- the 3th execution will allocate to [k+2] position and will be calculate the value and save into [k+2] position
- then the 2th function will use the [k+2] position to calculate their result
- then the 1th function will use the [k+1] position to calculate their result
- finally will return the value

[Some addtion information](https://medium.com/@allansendagi/javascript-fundamentals-call-stack-and-memory-heap-401eb8713204)